# ReactJS + Redux: What's the proper and correct practice to maintain state for a form?

Tags: javascript, html, redux, reactjs

In ReactJS + Redux, using Material-UI's `TextField`, http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field, I currently have a form where the user fills out firstName, lastName, birthMonth, birthDay, birthYear.

I have the following and it all works but seems like very redundant, especially for birth date, for example in terms of having action for every input and update it every change too:

In the component `InputComponent.js`:

```
  updateFirstName(event) {
    this.props.actions.updateFirstName(event.target.value)
  }

  updateLastName(event) {
    this.props.actions.updateLastName(event.target.value)
  }

  updateBirthMonth(event) {
    this.props.actions.updateBirthMonth(event.target.value)
  }

  updateBirthDay(event) {
    this.props.actions.updateBirthDay(event.target.value)
  }

  updateBirthYear(event) {
    this.props.actions.updateBirthYear(event.target.value)
  }

  <TextField
    hintText="Enter First Name"
    onChange={this.updateFirstName}
    value={this.props.userInfo.firstName}
  />
  <TextField
    hintText="Enter Last Name"
    onChange={this.updateLastName}
    value={this.props.userInfo.lastName}
  />
  <TextField
    hintText="Enter Birth Month"
    onChange={this.updateBirthMonth}
    value={this.props.userInfo.birthMonth}
  />
  <TextField
    hintText="Enter Birth Day"
    onChange={this.updateBirthDay}
    value={this.props.userInfo.birthDay}
  />
  <TextField
    hintText="Enter Birth Year"
    onChange={this.updateBirthYear}
    value={this.props.userInfo.birthYear}
  />
```

Then for my actions:

```
  updateFirstName(eventValue) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_FIRST_NAME',
      firstName: eventValue
    }
  },

  updateLastName(eventValue) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_LAST_NAME',
      lastName: eventValue
    }
  },

  updateBirthMonth(eventValue) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_BIRTH_MONTH',
      birthMonth: eventValue
    }
  },

  updateBirthDay(eventValue) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_BIRTH_DAY',
      birthDay: eventValue
    }
  },

  updateBirthYear(eventValue) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_BIRTH_YEAR',
      birthYear: eventValue
    }
  },
```

then in my reducer, `userReducer.js`:

```
const userReducer = function(userInfo = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_FIRST_NAME':
      return {
        ...userInfo,
        firstName: action.firstName
      }

    case 'UPDATE_LAST_NAME':
      return {
        ...userInfo,
        lastName: action.lastName
      }

    case 'UPDATE_BIRTH_MONTH':
      return {
        ...userInfo,
        birthMonth: action.birthMonth
      }

    case 'UPDATE_BIRTH_DAY':
      return {
        ...userInfo,
        birthDay: action.birthDay
      }

    case 'UPDATE_BIRTH_YEAR':
      return {
        ...userInfo,
        birthYear: action.birthyear
      }

    default:
      return userInfo
  }
}

export default userReducer
```

For ReactJS + Redux, is there a better, more proper and efficient practice to handle a form of inputs?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're doing it the right way. Lots of boilerplate is a common complaint. If you haven't looked it over, read through https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.md.

Answer (score 0):

Forewarning, I am very new to React and am just trying to provide a train of thought that is too big to be added as a comment. If this is a failure, I'll delete the answer...

Can you combine all the update functions into a single `updateUserInfo`?

```
// Component
<TextField name="firstName" onChange={this.updateUserInfo} ... />
<TextField name="lastName" onChange={this.updateUserInfo} ... />

updateUserInfo(event) {
  this.props.actions.updateUserInfo(event.target.name, event.target.value);
}

// Action
updateUserInfo(eventProperty, eventValue) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_USER_INFO',
      property: eventProperty,
      value: eventValue
    };
}

// Reducer
const userReducer = function(userInfo = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_USER_INFO':
      var returnObj = {
        ...userInfo
      };
      returnObj[action.property] = action.value;
      return returnObj;
  }
}
```

Alternative action and reducer:

```
// Action
updateUserInfo(eventProperty, eventValue) {
    var updatedData = {};
    updatedData[eventProperty] = eventValue;

    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_USER_INFO',
      data: updatedData
    };
}

// Reducer
const userReducer = function(userInfo = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'UPDATE_USER_INFO':
      return {
        ...userInfo,
        ...action.data
      };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to look at [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form).

Your form will be something like this ([example from here](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/getting-started?_k=3lceyg)):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const {fields: {firstName, lastName, email}, handleSubmit} = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" {...firstName}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" {...lastName}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" {...email}/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ContactForm = reduxForm({ // <----- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART!
  form: 'contact',                           // a unique name for this form
  fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email'] // all the fields in your form
})(ContactForm);

export default ContactForm;
```